# R: Use lines in xyplot to connet points from a specific variable level

Tags: r, graphics, scatter-plot, lattice

I have a data frame ***df*** with the following variables: ***Test***, ***A***, ***p*** and ***D***. I want to print ***A*** against ***p***, grouping by variable ***D*** levels.

I am using ***xyplot*** to do so and ***type=('p','l')*** to plot the points and the connecting lines between points. This procedure connects all points of the same level of variable ***D***. The problem is that I want to connect only the points from the same ***Test***.

Any clue how this can be done? Or if it is possible to do it with *xyplot*?

Example for data

```
    Test         A           p     D
95    32 0.0000000 0.010148395 55.04
96    32 0.2746429 0.018040352 55.04
97    32 1.0000000 0.019101864 55.04
271   72 0.0000000 0.005900593 22.64
272   72 0.1677419 0.006708547 22.64
273   72 0.4290323 0.009770698 22.64
274   72 1.0000000 0.010637487 22.64
275   73 0.0000000 0.005175419 22.64
276   73 0.2242424 0.006683234 22.64
277   73 0.3793939 0.009750174 22.64
278   73 1.0000000 0.012231502 22.64
```

This is the code I am using:

```
xyplot(A ~ p, data=df, groups=D, type=c("p","l"))
```

This is an example of what I would like to achieve. Maybe it is not possible with `xyplot`.

[Example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlAik.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example with sample input data.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve here? Settings `groups = Test` will connect the lines based on that variable, but what do you want to do with `p`? Color the points and lines according to it?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare variable `p` but connect only the points from the same `Test`. The problem is that if two or more `Test` has the same variable `p`, all the points of all tests will be connected.

Comment: I just added a drawing of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally get to solve this problem.

With data originally posted and the code

```
xyplot(A ~ p, data=df, groups=D, type=c("p","l"))
```

I get a scatter plot where points through different `Test` are connected against my will like in the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGZzU.jpg).

I add to "cheat" R in order to get what I wanted: connect only points from the same `Test`. To do that I added rows to the original data frame with `NA`values at the end of each `Test`.

```
   Test    A     p     D
1    32    0  0.01 35.04
2    32 0.27 0.018 35.04
3    32    1 0.019 35.04
4    32 <NA>  <NA> 35.04
5    72    0 0.006 12.64
6    72 0.17 0.007 12.64
7    72 0.43  0.01 12.64
8    72    1 0.011 12.64
9    72 <NA>  <NA> 12.64
10   73    0 0.005 12.64
11   73 0.22 0.007 12.64
12   73 0.38  0.01 12.64
13   73    1 0.012 12.64
14   73 <NA>  <NA> 12.64
```

And the result is showed in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JeV8.jpg).

I hope this post can help others.

Best regards

Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

Quite difficult to know for sure what you're asking. Do try to elaborate further with an example figure of what you want to achieve.

Anyway, here's a quick way using ggplot to show respective `A-p` plots for different levels of `D` and `Test`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(A, p)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(D~Test)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I pretend. I posted in the original post an image of what I am trying to achieve, but I imagine that is not possible with `xyplot`. Thanks anyway @AdamQuek.